# etree findall not working inside function

Tags: python

I am puzzled.
I have written this little piece of code before and used it somewhere else:

```
def testBut(p):
    print(root)
    for items in root.findall("a/item"):
        print(items.get("name"))
```

and it has worked just fine.

But now in my newer project i have the following code:

```
for items in root.findall("a/item"):
print(items.get("name"))

def testBut(p):
    print(root)
    for items in root.findall("a/item"):
        print(items.get("name"))
```

so OUTSIDE the def. it workes just fine, and shows me all the items in a, where as INSIDE the def i get nothing but root (because i print it). Can anyone explain why?

i am sorry if this is a repost or whatever, but i simply cannot find an answer, especially given it works just fine in a different file but exact same setup..

edit: full(ish) code.

```
from tkinter import *
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("Alphabet.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

colour0 = "WHITE"
colour1 = "OLIVEDRAB1"
colour2 = "PALETURQUOISE1"
colour3 = "ROSYBROWN1"
font1 = "Arial, 24"
counterRow = 1
counterColumn = 0

for items in root.findall("a/item"):
    print(items.get("name"))

def testBut(p):
    print(root)
    for items in root.findall("a/item"):
        print("test")
        print(items.get("name"))

def setup():
    for letters in root:
        global counterRow
        global counterColumn

        letters.tag = Button(vindue, text=letters.tag, font=font1,
                             command=lambda p=letters.tag: testBut(p))\
            .grid(row=counterRow, column=counterColumn, sticky="nsew")
        counterColumn += 1
        if counterColumn > 7:
            counterRow += 1
            counterColumn = 0


def reset():
    for buttons in vindue.grid_slaves():
        if buttons.grid_info()["row"] > 0:
            buttons.grid_forget()


def showBut(input):
    counter = 0
    reset()
    lst = []
    print(input)
    str = input+"/item"
    print(str)
    for items in root.findall("a/item"):
        print(items.get("name"))
        print("test")
        varstr = items.get("name")+"Var"
        varstr = IntVar()
        varstr2 = items.get("name")
        varstr2 = Button(vindue, text=items.get("name"), font="Arial, 44", command=lambda varstr=varstr: (varstr.set(varstr.get() + 1), print(varstr.get())))
        varstr2.grid(row=1, column=counter)
        counter += 1




vindue = Tk()

setup()

vindue.mainloop()
```

Comment: what are you saying... I try hard to understand but fail.

Comment: what is `root`? WHere are you setting it? Can you show us a complete example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: In your second code snippet, is there a missing indent in line 2?

Comment: That the for loop works outside my "testBut" def, but not inside, when i call it. I get the root print, but nothing from the for loop

Comment: Here you can see the full code. obviously the main idea is to use showBut(input) and use "str" instead of "a/item" in root.findall() but given it does not work i have made the testbut version just to figure out wth is going wrong..